# Drupal 8 Moving files between private and public folder on entity save

Tags: filenames, drupal-8, file-move

I am trying to hide files on a not published node. 
I use scheduler to publish nodes in the future and The files linked to that node cannot be publically accessible yet.
I moved them to the private folder.

But when the cron runs I have to move the file back to the original place. The problem here is that the file goes to the original folder but gets a _0 after the filename and uri.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_presave().
 */
function custom_configuration_entity_presave(EntityInterface $entity) {
  // Automatic fill in title field based on first and lastname.
  if($entity->getEntityTypeId() === 'node' && $entity->hasField('field_files')) {
    if($entity->isPublished()) {
      _custom_configuration_move_files($entity, 'public://', TRUE);
    }
    elseif (!$entity->isPublished()) {
      _custom_configuration_move_files($entity, 'private://', FALSE);
    }
  }
}
```

And my helper function to move the files

```
/**
 * Helper function to move a file
 * @param $entity
 *  the entity object
 * @param $target_stream_directory
 *  the stream directory
 * @param $published
 *  True or false if the entity is being published
 * 
 */
function _custom_configuration_move_files($entity, $target_stream_directory, $published) {
  // Get the files.
  $files_values = $entity->field_files->getValue();

  if(!empty($files_values)) {
    // Set the target directory. Either private or public/name_of_folder.
    $target_directory = $target_stream_directory;

    if($published) {
      // Add the field file directory to the target directory.
      $entity_definitions = $entity->getFieldDefinitions();
      $files_folder = $entity_definitions['field_files']->getSettings();
      $target_directory = $target_stream_directory . $files_folder['file_directory'];
    }

    // Loop over all files and move them.
    foreach($files_values as $file_value) {
      $file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($file_value['target_id']);
      $file = file_move($file, $target_directory, 'FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE');
    }
  }
}
```

But the scheduler on cron saves the file with a _0 on it.
I also tried to resave the file by changing the filename but that gives 'not found' because the file on the system is with a _0. 
So below does not work either

```
// Loop over all files and move them.
    foreach($files_values as $file_value) {
      $file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($file_value['target_id']);
      $file_name = $file->getFilename();
      $full_uri = $target_directory . '/' . $file_name;
      $file = file_move($file, $full_uri, 'FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE');
      $file->setFilename($file_name);
      $file->setFileUri($full_uri);
      $file->save();
    }
```

Can somebody point me in the right direction?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
$old_file_uri = $file->getFileUri();
$path_parts = pathinfo($old_file_uri);
$new_file_uri = $target_directory . '/' . $path_parts['basename'];
```